# Blocking a shell script's execution flow until prior processes finish?

Tags: shell, scripting

I've a list of jobs that I want to run in parallel and I call them all from one master script. Here is an example

```
echo "Starting jobs"
job1 &
job2 &
job3 &

# I want to wait until job1, job2 & job3 finishes on the multi core box
echo "Now I can proceed"
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`wait` is the command. Execution will not proceed beyond wait until the jobs are completed.

```
echo "Starting jobs"
job1 &
job2 &
job3 &

wait

# I want to wait until job1, job2 & job3 finishes on the multi core box
echo "Now I can proceed"
```